# .Net Core 3.1 API SSL Configuration for Docker

Tags: c#, docker, ssl, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I need to use SSL certificate for my api gateway and run it on the docker. I want to use the ssl certificate for port 5000. Since all my services using ports starts with 5000, i only apply SSL for gateway.

Lets say the domain is api.fabrikam.com:5000 and the docker container starts like:

```
docker run   -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production' -d -p 5000:5000 123456.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/gateway:latest
```

and also in the CreateWebHostBuilder method;

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) => {
                    config.AddJsonFile($"configuration.{host.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json");
                })
                 .UseKestrel(options =>
                 {
                     options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);  // http:localhost:5000
                     options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);         // http:*:80
                     options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443, listenOptions =>
                     {
                         listenOptions.UseHttps("api.fabrikam.com.pfx", "password");
                     });
                 })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

But when I call https://api.fabrikam.com:5000 no luck at all.
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: 5000 is the HTTP port. HTTPS runs on 5001

Answer (score 0):

Your startup command should like below:

```
docker run --rm -it
       -p 5000:80 
       -p 5001:443 
       -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" 
       -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 
       -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
       -v $Env:APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets\:
          /root/.microsoft/usersecrets 
       -v $Env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:
          /root/.aspnet/https/ 
       backend:latest
```

**For more details, you can refer this blog, it should be useful to you.**

[Set up HTTPS on local with .NET Core and Docker](http://Set%20up%20HTTPS%20on%20local%20with%20.NET%20Core%20and%20Docker)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time and interest. I am trying to achieve this in production, not in local environment. I dont even care local environment. Since I am using IIS to develop in local. I guess it's not the same config on production server.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy I mean have you try the command I provided about the port(5000 and 5001)?

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy Even in production environment,just replace the param about the aspnet_environment , the format of command is same.